# Get a sample video .MOV files

Tags: iphone

I need a sample video file for testing an iphone application.Can anyone tell a site from where i can download one and add to my resource file.

Answer (score 24):

Refer [apple sample video](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1425) link for sample video.

Comment: No longer working links

Comment: @Romias : links are working but due some problem in server there was some issue

Comment: The problem was that I was seeing the spanish version automatically (because of my browser settings)... going to the english version works. Thanks

Comment: You don't have permission to access "[no URL]" on this server.